# Changing Ruby and Rails version with capistrano and rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

What are the correct steps for changing the configuration of my project when change the ruby and rails version, using rmv.

For example, I have to change in deploy.rb `set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.4.0@5.1'`, but what else?

I can't get Capistrano use the correct rvm gemset, and allways tries to `bundle install` with the old rvm gemset

Do I have to change something in the production server? I think so, but in some order, before deploy and then after deploy some other changes...¿?

I have tried capistrano-rvm , rvm-capistrano, and finally rvm1-capistrano3

When I run cap production depoly, I get these errors, all arround "**Could not determine which Ruby to use**"

```
 DEBUG [e2eccae9] Running /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . bundle check --path /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/shared/bundle as rails@46.101.100.14

 DEBUG [e2eccae9] Command: cd /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/releases/20180303130204 && /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . bundle check --path /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/shared/bundle

 DEBUG [e2eccae9]   Could not determine which Ruby to use; . should contain .rvmrc or .versions.conf or .ruby-version or .rbfu-version or .rbenv-version, or an appropriate line in Gemfile.

 DEBUG [e2eccae9]   Can not find ruby for '.'.

 DEBUG [e2eccae9] Finished in 0.684 seconds with exit status 103 (failed).

  INFO [c22dc933] Running /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . bundle install --path /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet as rails@46.101.100.14

 DEBUG [c22dc933] Command: cd /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/releases/20180303130204 && /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . bundle install --path /home/rails/www/digitalshelving/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet

 DEBUG [c22dc933]   Could not determine which Ruby to use; . should contain .rvmrc or .versions.conf or .ruby-version or .rbfu-version or .rbenv-version, or an appropriate line in Gemfile.

 DEBUG [c22dc933]   Can not find ruby for '.'.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Rails.root* create file with name .ruby-version and following content:

```
2.3.3
```

or whatever version you want. When you or capistrano *cd* to root folder rvm will change ruby version according to file's content

Comment: Is not this the same as .rmvrv file? I'm already using it, What I ask is what are the steps to reproduce to change the ruby or rails version (definitely, to another rvm folder) with capistrano. capistrano can execute the rvm install itself? or this is something I have to do before?, in what order?...etc

Comment: Only before fitst deploy you have to install apropriate ruby version on target machine with rvm install 2.3.3 etc. After that you can tell in your deploy.rb file 
set :rvm_ruby_version, IO.read('.ruby-version') and capistrano will respect pointed version

Comment: I finally could get it working, but with some stumbles. I didn't say it is so easy as you say, the first thing I did is `set :rvm1_ruby_version, '2.4.0@5.1', this "rvm1_ruby..." is referring the gem, I changed the gem various times... but, anyway, the next thime I will try this as you say againg. Thanks for your interest